# Managing workflow with wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, android-activity, workflow-foundation-4

i have a problem.
I would like to create a WCF service, exposing only one method. This WCF service must interact , behind the scene, with a Workflow (created with WF 4.5).
By calling that method, in different moments, the workflow will be executed and the state has to be restored (i think bookmarks can be useful for me).

Is it possible? Or i have to expose all methods ? (In this scenario, i imagine that a wcf service would be useful for façading) .
How can i manage context? Do i have to use Receive Activity and SendReplyToReceive or not?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ask one question at the time please, right now you've asked for a full chapter of a book.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information on exactly what work you would like the workflow to perform? You say that "the workflow will be executed and the state has to be restored". What state do you want to have restored? In general the flow you mention of calling a WCF service which then calls workflow sounds acceptable.
Windows Workflow almost always is initiated with a Receive Activity. Whether or not you need a SendReplyToReceive depends upon what, if any, information you want communicated back to the wcf service.